# Date format in hive

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

table has DEPNO   DATE            it contains 2 records as :
           1      2004-05-02
           2      03-APR-04 
I want to process above 2 records dates in in yyyy-mm-dd format in hive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try in following way:

```
select TO_DATE(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(recordDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))) from table_name
```

Refer [Hive Date Functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) for more details

Answer (score 0):

couple of options
 1. Use UDF to take the column and return what ever format you want.
 2. Use case when statement like

```
select CASE WHEN length(col) = 10 then unix_timestamp(col, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
      else unix_timestamp(col, 'yy-MMM-dd') from whatever.
```